# My external hard drive was suddently delete my files and make the storage inaccessible. I just try to recover my info. (superblock)

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I wrote “fsck” on my terminal to check or repair my files , just to try to repair my hard drive, and the terminal show me this.

```
   sudo fsck -p /dev/sdc

fsck from util-linux 2.34 fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open
 /dev/sdc /dev/sdc:  The superblock could not be read or does
 not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.  If the device
 is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
 (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
 is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate
 superblock:
            e2fsck -b 8193 <device>  or
            e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

**fdisk -l and shows this:**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.84 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 0748
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x69205244

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        218129509 1920119918 1701990410 811.6G 72 unknown
/dev/sdc2        729050177 1273024900  543974724 259.4G 74 unknown
/dev/sdc3        168653938  168653938          0     0B 65 Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdc4       2692939776 2692991410      51635  25.2M  0 Empty
```

**On Gparted** the file system of my external drive is unknow, and show this error.
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:

- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sdc is missing

If i try to mount
**sudo mount /dev/sdc**

```
mount: /dev/sdc: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

**I tried mount and check partition:**

```
sudo fsck -p /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Possibly non-existent device?

sudo mount /dev/sdc2
mount: /dev/sdc2: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Try mounting (and checking) a partition, not the device.  sdc1 instead of sdc or maybe sdc2.

Comment: Did you dd an ISO file to the external drive. The unknown partitions are typical of that hybrid DVD/flash drive written to a device. It overwrites the normal partition table and the first part of the drive. Does testdisk show anything? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
repairs including testdisk info & links
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition

Comment: How old is the drive?

Comment: I tried mount and check partition:  sudo fsck -p /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Possibly non-existent device?

Comment: My drive maybe have 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

I had several of these passport devices and all of them have displayed dismal reliability over time.

Sometimes I can get the device back by creating a new GPT partition table (Gparted, select drive, click on the device tab in the menu bar, then create new partition table.  Select GPU from the pulldown).  This will, of course, destroy any existing data structures on the device. With the new partition table down create a new primary partition and format it with your file system of choice.

Or, you can do what I eventually did to mine...contribute them to the local electronics recycler and seek something more reliable.